troubleshooting an electrooculography (EOG) circuit
I have been trying to deign an electrooculography (EOG) circuit using TL072 chips. This is my first time working with amplifiers and as such it has been a lot of new material.
I am basing my design off of this setup (source):

I have built a mockup circuit on breadboards, but so far my results have been inconclusive.
The final product should be able to interface with an Arduino Uno.

Within the active feedback portion, I can identify what I believe is an op-amp in a voltage follower configuration (to buffer the signal from the preamp,) and an active (inverting) low pass filter. Is this evaluation correct?
What should the low pass filter be set to? Should it be the same as the low pass present in the band pass filter portion? If not, what should it be?


Evidently, EOG is "Electrooculogram" -- i.e., measuring eye movement.

If you want to actually troubleshoot a circuit, you'll have an easier time just telling us the problem you're seeing.  That will save many iterations.

All the design details are in the source document you posted. See chapter "4.4. Active Feedback Circuit" and "4.3. Filtering"

Are you sure that TL072 is an appropriate replacement amplifier for OPA2335? (It's not an instrumentation amp, so I assume you didn't replace the INA333 with it)

As the paper states, this application "requires a  careful PCB layout" a breadboard is about as far from "a careful PCB layout" as possible.

The low pass filter frequency should be set according to what you are trying to do with the signal.
If you want to know where the eye is looking so you can determine if it's looking at a target, I'd make the cutoff frequency less than 50 or 60 Hz, to avoid electrical noise.  This just makes your design a bit easier.
If you're trying to accurately capture the dynamics of the fastest eye movements (i.e., saccades) You need it to be at least 120Hz, maybe even as high as 200Hz.
You would then need to sample at at least twice the filter cutoff frequency

okay, I think I'm following you.
the sampling rate of an arduino uno is apparently around 64Hz from what I am reading. The final idea is to have a system where someone can use this circuit to interact with a computer, basic inputs so I think your first idea is more applicable.
question: how should I decide how much lower than 50 or 60 Hz to make it?
question 2: just wondering, if I were to be trying that second option, why does that require a higher cutoff frequency?
question 3: is that last statement true for both options? and is that the answer to question 1 (lol)
thanks

A saccade lasts in it's entirely less than 0.150 seconds.  Let's say that you'd like to capture the dynamics of a saccade, and to do that you feel you need to acquire 15 points during the event -- well that's 100 Hz sample rate.  The last statement is pretty universally true for accurate alias-free sampling (look up aliasing).  Your needs may be able to tolerate aliasing, but I can't really tell you if that's true.

just to be sure, does that rule for the sample rate and cutoff frequency relationship applies to the band pass filter too right?

Just the low pass filter cutoff, @KPUGGaming
